# Solving equations with ceiling function

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\lceil x\rceil$ denote the value of the ceiling function at $x.$ Consider two distinct odd primes $p$ and $q.$ I want to find integers $n$ (if exixts) between $0$ and $pq$, and non-negative integers $a,b, c, d$ such that it satisfies the following equations together:

$$a+2c+ \lceil \frac{n}{p}\rceil = \lceil \frac{n+a+2b+2c+2d}{p}\rceil$$

$$a+2d +\lceil  \frac{n}{q}\rceil = \lceil \frac{n+a+2b+2c+2d}{q}\rceil$$

$$a+ \lceil \frac{n}{pq}\rceil = \lceil \frac{n+a+2b+2c+2d}{pq}\rceil$$

Thank you in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @BenMillwood: Yes, you are right. I have changed the question into a general form question.

Comment: hmm, but now I can just choose $a = b = c = d = 0$, and then any choice of $n$ works. Is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: can you specify whether $0 < n < pq$ or $0 \le n \le pq$ (i.e. is $n = 0$ or $n = pq$ allowed?)

Comment: @BenMillwood: I want the $4$-tuple (a,b,c,d) to be non zero in $\mathbb{N}^{\times 4}$. Also, n=0 is allowed but not $pq.$ But I am expecting all possible solutions.